# Wordpress plugin for Google Maps that will dynamically receive addresses required

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

After much trawling and emailing of sales people, I have been unsuccessful in finding a Wordpress plugin for Google Maps that will work with a database.

All the plugins I have seen so far use a control panel for manually adding the addresses. I have over 1000 addresses which are searched for by users with maximum results of 250.

I would like those results to appear on a map (it doesn't have to be a Google map).

The current search engine within my Wordpress site is a custom written PHP file with a request from the functions.php file based on the page url, i.e. the shopping page brings up a shopping search box.
The database is MySQL.

Does anyone know of a plugin that will work with a database for dynamic results based on user input?
I've tried using Googles' API directly but I only write basic PHP and found it completely confusing with help files that only give circular links so I'd rather pay for a good plugin with support if it's available.

Thanks.

Comment: you could try this: WP Google Map Plugin

Comment: Try some of these http://designscrazed.com/wordpress-google-map-plugins/
However, you'll need some sort of PHP/MySQL knowledge in order to rework/insert your current data coordinates in tables of any plugin.

Comment: Thanks Dk-Macadamia, I've contacted the makers, Flippercode and they can make the MySQL integration for a fee, which is great.